# HTML encode string builder

Tags: .net, string, stringbuilder

We have [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to HTML-encode a string, but if you're using a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), is there a way to HTML-encode it before you output the string?  I would like to build some content using the string builder, then HTML encode it, then apply some additional post-encoding HTML tags before outputting it (via `ToString`), all while maintaining the benefit of the string builder vis-a-vis immutability, interning, etc.

Comment: Short answer no. StringBuilder is for building strings, not encoding text. If you want to combine these you could inherit from StringBuilder and override the ToString method to encode the string before outputting but that may be over complicating something which can be done in 2 lines of code...

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve? (Besides doing the two things in one operation)

Comment: Well, I just want to build the string and manipulate it (i.e. HTML-encode it) without creating a bunch of copies of it in memory, i.e. I want to take advantage of the automatic interning, etc. baked into string builder.

Comment: What about encoding the strings as you added them to the StringBuilder?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I thought of that afterward.  That would work.  This is a non-stopping issue anyway, so it's not really that big of a deal.  Again, thanks for taking the time to reply.  I appreciate it.